# Unable to get access token. 'AADSTS500011: The resource principal named 'xxx' was not found in the tenant -tenantid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to get the access token for the Azure function app. I have enabled `managed identity for the function App (system assigned)`, but while fetching the token using the `Azure.Identity` nuget package

```
var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
                                    new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { "https://xxx.azure-api.net/" + "/.default" }) { }
                                    );
```

I am getting the below error.

> The resource principal named 'app-name.azure-api.net' was not found in
> the tenant "tenant-name"

but when I run `az cli` to check the subscription details, the subscription indeed part of the tenant only.

Comment: You may be missing the scope, try to change it to: `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.default`.

Comment: I have tried, its still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I have finally done.

1. I have registered an App in AD. and Exposed the API of that App.
2. I have assigned System Assigned Managed Identity to the Function.
3. In the local I am not able to request token because Azure CLI is not given consent.
4. After deploying the application in Function my Function app can request a token using its identity.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the error message is not really helpful. But adding a scope to the app registration solved the problem for me:

- In Azure Portal navigate to App Registrations
- Find your app, in the left side menu select Manage => Expose an API
- Add a scope. I named mine `api_access` as this was where this error occurred.

In my case I then got an API URI (like api://client-id/scope_name) which I used in my Angular app. Error message was gone.

Also, make sure that in the Enterprise Application you have created, under Manage => Properties, "Assignment required" and "Visible to users" is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the application in azure ad and enable the access token. Once that is done the you need to provide RBAC access to your xxx.azurewebsites.net

[image]

Follow this article for the step by step documentation  [Microsoft Document Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: I am using system generated identity and not user identity. so, I havent registered any application in AD